# Parse Error, missing a closing "}"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've spent 45mins looking for the missing closing "}" and I can't find it. I rewrote the code and I still get this error. What am I doing wrong?

**Parser Error Message:** The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Line 9:  @foreach (var item in Model) {

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  int checkId = item.Id;
  if (item.ReplyId == checkId){
    <div>
      <h4>Forum</h4>
      <hr />
      <div class="panel panel-default">

      <div class="panel-heading">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Body)
      </div>
      </div>
  }
}
@foreach(var item2 in Model)
{
  if(item2.ReplyId == checkId){
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Body)

      </div>
      </div>
  }
}

<p>
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  string user = item.User;
  if (User.Identity.Name == user)
  {
    <p>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = checkId }) |</p>
      <p>@Html.ActionLink("Reply", "Reply", new { id = checkId }) |</p>

  }
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
}
```

Comment: i've notice on your code that you declare the checkId only on the first @foreach, and use it on other code blocks.

Comment: Right but that's not causing the issue is it?

Comment: I notice a </div> in the end of the foreach that is breaking the entire markup

Comment: @Fals I agree with you.

Comment: i dont think is causing the issue but could be a problem on your code since the value is not the right for the other blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must wrap long closures in @{ } brackets.  I believe this is your issue:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { 
    //... 
}
```

Try:

```
@{ 
    if(Request.IsAuthenticated) { 
        //... 
    } 
}
```

Wrapping all html/text elements with `<text></text>` tags

Comment: Thanks guys, this and the comment Fals made fixed it.

Comment: @NoahR You don't need to wrap the block with an extra set of braces. Razor works perfectly fine the way you have it - it's normal to do `@if (something) { <div></div> }`, same for things like `foreach` or other similar syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

your missing a closing "/div" In this code:  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Body). That might be why it errors out.

Answer (score 0):

It's your unclosed `div` in the first block, and an extra closing `/div` in your second block. Razor is very picky about that kind of thing.

Once you fix those, you'll run into some other syntax issues, like `item` not being defined in your third block, but you should be able to deal with those.